# Unable to authenticate in Jhipster

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm create an application using Jhipster stack and development on Windows 10, here is application config

```
application {
  config {
    baseName xxx
    applicationType monolith
    packageName com.xxx
    authenticationType jwt
    prodDatabaseType mysql
    devDatabaseType mysql
    buildTool gradle
    cacheProvider redis
    clientFramework angularX
    serverPort 8090
    websocket spring-websocket
  }
  entities *
}
```

The problem is I can't even login to the default account or register the new one.

I tried to find the solution and got that someone put `-Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true` into VM options will work but I'm not. Especially, this error only occur on Windows, I tried to run this app without any modifier on Macos and it's working normally. But Macos is not my primary development enviroment then I have to make it work on Windows, thanks

Jhipster info:

```
<summary>.yo-rc.json file</summary>
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationIndex": 0,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "baseName": "xxx",
    "blueprints": [],
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "cacheProvider": "redis",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "creationTimestamp": 1652962669893,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "devServerPort": 4200,
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "enableGradleEnterprise": false,
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "entities": ["Movie", "Actor", "Category", "Country", "Manufacturer", "Link"],
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "gradleEnterpriseHost": "",
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "jhipsterVersion": "7.8.1",
    "jwtSecretKey": "YourJWTSecretKeyWasReplacedByThisMeaninglessTextByTheJHipsterInfoCommandForObviousSecurityReasons",
    "languages": ["en"],
    "lastLiquibaseTimestamp": 1652963029000,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "otherModules": [],
    "packageFolder": "com/xxx",
    "packageName": "com.xxx",
    "pages": [],
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "reactive": false,
    "searchEngine": false,
    "serverPort": "8090",
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "skipCheckLengthOfIdentifier": false,
    "skipFakeData": false,
    "skipUserManagement": false,
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "websocket": "spring-websocket",
    "withAdminUi": true
  }
}

##### **Environment and Tools**

openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.15+10 (build 11.0.15+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.15+10 (build 11.0.15+10, mixed mode)

git version 2.33.0.windows.2

node: v16.15.1

npm: 8.11.0

Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

Docker Compose version v2.6.1
```

[Here is the error log](https://gist.github.com/dungreact/4a3dfd5b53674018feb49c413f299b09) It's long then I created a gist.

Comment: Are you running same JDK version on both Windows and macOS? If you haven't modified generated projects and you are using latest version of JHipster, you should consider provide more information (`jhipster info`) on similar issue on github: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/18910

Comment: The SDK is the same, I will add it

Comment: The jhipster info was supposed to be added to github issue not here because it's formatted for github markdown flavor.

Comment: Have you tried using tomcat instead of undertow? (jh issue [#18440](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/18440))

Comment: @vicpermir of course, it doesn't work, it's missing javax.servlet package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, in the configurations, tomcat has been excluded, I remove that line and change undertow to tomcat then it's work. Thanks!